# How do you go to the end of the file in journalctl?

Tags: journalctl

If I type `sudo journalctl` I get the system journal in some kind of a reader. Pressing j and k works like in Vi but G does not go to the end of the file. In fact, if press G, the stream freezes and I have forcibly terminate it.

No mention of using the reader is in the man page for journalctl.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

that "reader" is just `less`.

> No mention of using the reader is in the man page for journalctl.

err, said man page:

> ```
> The output is paged through `less` by default,
> ```

but:

> but G does not go to the end of the file. In fact, if press G, the stream freezes and I have forcibly terminate it.

G works beautifully, the log is just very long, so it's searching for a long time until it reaches the end.

from the man page:

> ```
>   -e, --pager-end
>       Immediately jump to the end of the journal inside the implied pager 
>       tool. This implies -n1000 to guarantee that the pager will not buffer 
>       logs of unbounded size. This may be overridden with an explicit -n 
>       with some other numeric value, while -nall will disable this cap. 
>       Note that this option is only supported for the less(1) pager.
> ```

So,

```
journalctl -e
```

is what you want to run!

Comment: Or pass `--no-pager` if you just want to see it and now have it stop.

Comment: Note that adding `--pager-end` seems to trim the output to 1000 latest lines.

Comment: @Osman-pasha is it trimmed or is that the size of your console buffer?

Comment: @Blaise it's trimmed by `journalctl` itself, as per `man` (see the text in the answer):

Comment: _"G works beautifully, the log is just very long, so it's searching for a long time until it reaches the end."_ That's for sure! It takes like a minute to find the end of this file with this command. I bet this file is gigabytes in size.

Answer (score 3):

Adding onto [@Marcus Müller's excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/654562/114401):

```bash
# show only the last 1000 lines of the systemd journal (`-n 1000` is implied),
# jumping straight to the end (`-e`)
journalctl -e

# same as above
journalctl -n 1000 -e

# same as above, except show the last 10000 lines instead of 1000 lines
journalctl -n 10000 -e
```

You can prove this is working by counting the lines. Run and output:

```bash
$ journalctl -n 10000 -e | wc -l
10020
```

This is soooo much faster than running `journalctl` directly, as my log is loooooooooong, and it takes like a full minute to read to the end of it otherwise.